# Need help translating raw sql query to ORM Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Django Models that used in projects:

```
class LeadStatus(models.Model):
    status_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='ID статуса', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Имя', null=True, default='Неизвестный')

class Lead(models.Model):
    lead_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="ID сделки", null=True, unique=True)
    created_date_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Время и дата создания сделки", null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Бюджет сделки')
    current_status = models.ForeignKey(LeadStatus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Текущий статус', null=True)


class LeadsNote(models.Model):
    note_id = models.CharField(verbose_name="ID примечания", null=True, unique=True, max_length=64)
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    old_status = models.ForeignKey(LeadStatus, related_name='old_status', null=True, blank=True,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_status = models.ForeignKey(LeadStatus, null=True, related_name='new_status', blank=True,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    crossing_status_date_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Время и дата пересечения статуса", null=True)
```

I am trying to execute the following SQL query using Django ORM tools. He does what i need

```
SELECT leads.id, 
       notes.crossing_status_date_time,
       old_status.name as old_status,
       new_status.name as new_status,
       (CASE WHEN leads.id in (
        select leads.id
        from core_leads
        where old_status.status_id not in (13829322, 14286379) and new_status.status_id in (13829322, 14286379))
      THEN true ELSE false END)  as _is_profit
FROM core_leadsnote AS notes
LEFT JOIN core_lead AS leads ON notes.lead_id=leads.id
LEFT JOIN core_leadstatus AS old_status ON notes.old_status_id=old_status.id
LEFT JOIN core_leadstatus AS new_status ON notes.new_status_id=new_status.id
```

Using Django subqueries I came up with the following ORM query.
But it doesn't work as well as raw sql

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Q, Subquery, Case, When, BooleanField

from .models import LeadsNote, Lead, CompanyConfig, AmoCompany

company = AmoCompany.objects.first()
status_config = CompanyConfig.objects.get(company=company)
accepted_statuses = [status.status_id for status in status_config.accept_statuses.all()]

subquery = (Lead
            .objects.select_related('current_status', 'company')
            .filter(leadsnote=OuterRef('pk'))
            .filter(~Q(leadsnote__old_status__status_id__in=accepted_statuses) &
                    Q(leadsnote__new_status__status_id__in=accepted_statuses)))

query = (LeadsNote
            .objects
            .annotate(
                _is_profit=Case(
                    When(lead__id__in=Subquery(subquery.values('id')), then=True),
                    default=False, output_field=BooleanField())))
```

Need any help finding the right solution

Comment: `core_lead` - is this a typo or something else then `core_leads`? Where did `company` come from? I don't see it neither in original query nor in model links. Also I reckon you're having troubles with `_is_profit` column only, so I suggest you to resolve the main part of the select which seems to be pretty trivial, then to move on solving this tricky column.

Comment: Also not clear why you used subquery in given sql select statement: `leads.id` is a PK, so `leads.id IN (select other_leads.id` can match only the same row. You already have it in the first LEFT JOIN, just compare column values to what you need.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, эквивалента ли запись в pure sql которая аннотирует _is_profit подзапросом той записи в ORM, которая пытается делать тоже самое? По моим ощущениям это идентичные вещи, но судя по логам запрос ORM транслируется в немного другой SQL запрос. Значит ли это, что беда в слишком абстрагированном ORM или дело в кривом использовании?

Comment: In russian questions can be asked at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: As said 1) the original query does not seem right 2) shown orm query does not match the original query in many details 3) could be this as an XY problem so please try describing the original task you're trying to accompish. Give us sample data and desired result.